# How to store HTML headings in JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, html

I have an javascript array that is hard coded into my javascript file:

```
var avatar_layers = new Array('background', 'body', 'hair', 'shirt', 'arms', 'legs', 'feet', 'weapon')
```

As it is hardcoded, it is difficult to use it between different HTML files.

I would like to change it so the javascript will look for all the h3 tags that have a class of title on the page and use the content of these tags to create the array.

How can I do this?

After reading around, I have found that I should use the following

> document.getElementsByTagName("h3.title")[0];

This will get all the h3.titles. However, I am not sure how to output the collected data as array.

I would really appreciate any pointers. Thanks!

**Update: I can't use Jquery, it has to be regular java script**

**You can see my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/zk5Hn/2/**

Comment: what do you mean by "output data as array"? output where? in console?

Comment: @gryzzly The array I have posted is used later on in the script. So I want the values of the array to come from the HTML in my page. Is that possible?

Comment: Sure it is. You want to store the titles from HTML in an array? Is that correct?

Comment: @grryzzly Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
​var array = [];

(function(){
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("h3");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        array.push(elements[i].innerText);
    }
})();

​alert(array);​
```

try that.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jsckt/

alternatively you could use jquery:

```
$(function(){
    var array = [];

    $("h3.title").each(function() {
        array.push(this.innerText);
    });

    alert(array);
}​;​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jsckt/2/

5 years later edit:

1. one should avoid using innerText theese days for performance and expectational reasons
2. you can explode DOM node lists to arrays now

there you go with a up2date solution for 2018 onwards:

```
const headings = [...document.querySelectorAll("h3.title")].map(node => node.textContent);
alert(headings);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried that but it doesn't work. Here is my code before I made any modifications: http://jsfiddle.net/zk5Hn/2/  Here is my code afterwards: http://jsfiddle.net/qrSEM/. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: doesnt run because you run it before the html is loaded.

Comment: you must eather wrap it into a function that you call like: <body onload="init();"> or like window.onload = function(){/*content here*/};

Comment: you srsly should use jquery cause there you only need to do: $(function(){/*content here*/}); to fire it when the dom is ready to be modified

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hkuVM/1/ there. an update to your code. (just modified it on the right side so it runs when the dom is ready)

Comment: Yes, you are right about Jquery. I think I'm going to redo the project and use it. It is a big time saver. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

No, [`document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) will not apply the class selector, you'd need to use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.querySelectorAll) for that (and because it is not supported by legacy browsers like IE, you might need to use a selector library or some other workarounds).

Then, you got a `NodeList` back which already is like an array of elements. Iterate over it and add the contents of each element to your array:

```
var headingEls = document.querySelectorAll("h3.title");
var avatar_layers = []; // empty array literal
for (var i=0; i<headingEls.length; i++)
    avatar_layers.push(headingEls[i].textContent);
```

Don't forget that you can access the elements not until the DOM is loaded, you will need to execute that snippet on a `domready` event; you can't use the array immidiately.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
var titles = document.querySelectorAll('.title'),
    avatar_layers = [];
for( var i=0; i<titles.length; i++ ) {
    avatar_layers.push( titles[i].innerHTML );
}
```

It will create a new, empty array. Then look inside all elements that has the class `.title` and extract it’s HTML content. Then push this content into the array.

Using jQuery it would be very simple:

```
var avatar_layers = $('.title').map(function(){
    return $(this).html();
});
```

Is this what you want?

Note that `querySelectorAll` is not supported in IE7-, so you’ll need a library like jQuery or some other workaround if you need support for those browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
var h3s = document.getElementsByTagName("h3");

var arr = [].map.call(h3s, function(el) {
                              return el.textContent || el.innerText;
                           });
```

You can get a patch for `.map` in old browsers here: [MDN `.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery then,

```
var titleArray = new Array();
$('h3.title').each(function(){
    titleArray.push($(this).text());
});

alert(titleArray);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/WVsEB/3/

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I can't use jqeury for this project!

Answer (score 1):

Older versions of Javascript haven't a nativ method to select elements by the attribute 'class'. In the past I found a selfcreated method to fill that gap. You can find the workaround [here](http://www.anyexample.com/webdev/javascript/javascript_getelementsbyclass_function.xml) . This function does work for IE6 either

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that code in the link, but it doesn't seem to work. Here is my code before: http://jsfiddle.net/zk5Hn/2/ and after: http://jsfiddle.net/33Lyb/ Could you give me some pointers? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly does not work? The method to find tags with class attribute?

Comment: The class works. you made a mistike in defining the variable scope. The definition of variable 'avatar_layers' must be moved into the global scope and not within a function. The call of ..ByClass() either.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h3 class = 'title'>trtr</h3>
<h3 class = 'title'>tcrtr</h3>
<h3 class = 'title'>tdrtr</h3>
<h3 class = 'title'>trrtr</h3>
<h3>trgtr</h3>

var arrayDemo  = [];
$.each($('h3[class*=title]'), function () {
         arrayDemo.push(this.innerHTML);
});

alert(arrayDemo);
```

Here is the demo for this
http://jsfiddle.net/ymtFg/

Comment: This assumes you will be using Jquery Library

Comment: Oh That's why it wasn't working. I can't use Jquery for this!